# Is sky finite in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Probably sky is finite in Minecraft but I can't seem to reach the end of it. I can't go higher than 256 blocks (or whatever is defined in the `server.properties` file) with WorldEdit, but when flying I can actually go higher.

So, if sky is finite (which it probably is), then where is the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can fly as high as your want in Creative or Spectator mode. However, you cannot place any blocks above y256. This is why you can't fly above y256 in MCEdit.

Comment: What I meant with 'the end' is not 'The End', but literally the end of the sky.

Comment: Also I'm talking about just the sky in the overworld.

Comment: Hold on, I'll edit it in a moment

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards Then as you say in the question and as this answer says, You can place blocks up to 256, but the game has no issue with you flying up forever. Presumably the same code that 'ends' the world in X and Z directions will also end it in the Y direction

Comment: @SPCOxion Thanks for the edit :) Now the answer is simple and it actually answers the question. I'll accept it in a minute.

Comment: I assume the same would be true of the reverse. Theoretically, it is possible to fly infinitely downward past bedrock, but the game has a death mechanism if you try.

Comment: Notice that the limit can be increased with mods or server's properties

Comment: @iKiWiXz I'm fairly certain that 256 is the highest Y that is supported by the [Anvil Format](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Anvil_file_format), increasing it via server.properties won't work

Comment: @MrLemon You're right. The server.propeties setting is just able to lower the limit.

Comment: In older versions if you went above a certain Y altitude, the game would display an odd error message and your world would be completely unusable due to you being stuck above that height.

Comment: If you go up VERY high (use /tp) while it rains, the rain glitches: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-50142

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It is limited to Y:4,503,599,627,370,494.179. Any player above this level will be automatically kicked out of the server for the reason "Illegal stance".
See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWGA0HRi6vg&t=416) for more information.

Comment: For anyone interested, that's 2^52. Presumably they are using a 64-bit integer to store Y coordinates, so the remaining values are used for negative Y coords (and 0).

Comment: @Alex: It's a 64-bit *floating point* number (AKA double-precision), which is why the limit is 2^52, not 2^64 - double-precision floating point only has 53 bits of precision, so at that value, the "gaps" between adjacent numbers become too big.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen I admit I made a superquick assumption based purely on the number. Thanks for the info.